# SSL cert for AWS domain?

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, django-rest-framework, aws-fargate

I have a backend service i'm running in Fargate. I need this service to have an SSL cert on its load balancer so that it can talk to other HTTPS services. I've created the load balancer and it gives me an AWS domain (my-cool-app.us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com).

Now, when I try to request a certificate through acm, it fails and says "Additional verification required". So i'm not sure if it's possible to add an SSL cert to this load balancer without registering a custom domain?

Also, this is a Django app and I haven't done anything other than keep it as `runserver` which I know isn't good for production but I just need to start by making it work as a dev environment. Do I need to change the way Django runs in order for SSL to work? Or is the load balancer sufficient?

Answer (score 0):

To use an SSL for a domain you need to have control over that domain. For the AWS managed certificate service ([ACM](https://aws.amazon.com/certificate-manager/)) you can verify through either [DNS validation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/acm/latest/userguide/gs-acm-validate-dns.html) or [email validation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/acm/latest/userguide/gs-acm-validate-email.html) both of which you must essentially have domain control to validate.

As you're trying to use ACM for a AWS owned domain, someone from AWS would need to approve the SSL (which they won't).

Regarding your second point what you're describing is SSL offloading, in which the load balancer will serve HTTPS and then terminate encryption in transit. It will then forward the request to the Fargate container using the protocol and port defined in the target group.

The only thing you want to consider is how you display to the user, for example ensure that all CSS, JS ans links on your site are HTTPS. You can detect whether the incoming request used HTTPS at the load balancer by inspecting the `X-Forwarded-Proto` header in your application.

Comment: Ok, so if AWS owns the domain, how do i add SSL to it? Would I instead run the Django server as HTTPS and leave the load balancer on port 80?

Comment: So assuming you're trying to get the SSL for the AWS ELB domain, on someone who has domain access to the `*.amazonaws.com` domain could perform the DNS validation. Hence this will eventually fail as Amazon will not add it :)

Comment: You would want HTTPS on at least the point of interaction from the client to your outer most resource so you would not want to have HTTP on the load balancer but HTTPS on the target. The SSL itself needs to be both from a valid CA and for the hostname your users connect to in order to be secure :)

Comment: Ok, so basically, I need to buy a domain first

Comment: Only if you want to display securely, otherwise you could still upload a self signed SSL to ACM. It would just not be a valid CA so would show as insecure but would allow you to attach to the ALB

Comment: It makes sense after doing some research because other platforms that manage your sever / ssl (heroku etc) will automatically give you an SSL cert, but that makes sense because (I think) they run on AWS they're just requesting a cert from AWS but they have control of the heroku domain. So you get it for your application by default. But on AWS, you have to do everything 